# PyTables Read From Large CSV in chunks :

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, hdf5, pytables

I have the following code that is reading from a CSV and writing to PyTables. However, pd.read_csv creates a dataframe and this is not handled in PyTables. How do I solve this problem? I can create numpy arrays but this seems like over kill and possibly time consuming? (Transaction Record is a class i created with the right data types - i have to replicate this if using numpy)

```
def get_transaction_report_in_chunks(transaction_file):
   transaction_report_data = pd.read_csv(transaction_file, index_col=None, parse_dates=False, chunksize=500000)
   return transaction_report_data

def write_to_hdf_from_multiple_csv(transaction_file_path):
   hdf = tables.open_file(filename='MyDB.h5', mode='a')
   transaction_report_table = hdf.create_table(hdf.root, 'Transaction_Report_Table_x', Transaction_Record, "Transaction Report Table")
   all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(transaction_file_path, "*.csv"))
   for transaction_file in all_files:
       for transaction_chunk in get_transaction_report_in_chunks(transaction_file):
         transaction_report_table.append(transaction_chunk)
         transaction_report_table.flush()
  hdf.Close()
```

Comment: Is there a good reason for not using a standard Pandas `DataFrame.to_hdf()` or `HDFStore.append`, etc.?

Comment: Not really. I am just not sure if this is good enough for large datasets and for querying the table on specific columns. The other problem would be if the query returned results that cannot be computed in memory I am not sure how i would handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [Pandas HDF Store](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#hdfstore), which is very convinient API for PyTables under the hood:

```
def write_to_hdf_from_multiple_csv(csv_file_path,
                                   hdf_fn='/default_path/to/MyDB.h5',
                                   hdf_key='Transaction_Report_Table_x',
                                   df_cols_to_index=True): # you can specify here a list of columns that must be indexed, i.e.: ['name', 'department']
    files = glob.glob(os.path.join(csv_file_path, '*.csv'))
    # create HDF file (AKA '.h5' or PyTables)
    store = pd.HDFStore(hdf_fn)
    for f in files:
        for chunk in pd.read_csv(f, chunksize=500000):
            # don't index data columns in each iteration - we'll do it later ...
            store.append(hdf_key, chunk, data_columns=df_cols_to_index, index=False)
    # index data columns in HDFStore
    store.create_table_index(hdf_key, columns=df_cols_to_index, optlevel=9, kind='full')
    store.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How do i specify the data type the column should take - can i pass a class / dict. Also is there a way i can view this? With Pytables you can view

Comment: @CodeGeek123, you don't have to specify dtypes - it will be inherited from DF columns dtypes. And `store = pd.HDFStore('/path/to/file_name.h5'); print(store.get_storer('your_hdf_key').table)` should give all the details about dtypes,indexes, etc.